# Do epoxy and shelac-based paint mix well together?

Tags: painting, paint, kitchen-counters, countertops, epoxy

I have a lot of clear epoxy resin intended for use on MDF or formica or partical board kitchen countertops.

I want to dye half of the epoxy white and dye half of the epoxy grey and do a fake marble look.

I do not want the white shelac-based paint and epoxy to seperate.

Does white shellac based paint mix well with epoxy or do the two seperate like oil and water?

Comment: Don't use paint. Use pigment

Comment: Last time I used a brush to paint some epoxy paint and tried to clean the brush with thinner, the stuff turned into cottage cheese. So *since you are asking generally*, the answer is "HARD no".

Comment: Do you want it to separate?  last time I had paint separate on me it was by applying a second coat before the first was dry enough.  I got a marbled effect as the pigments separated but I didn't want it.

Answer (score 2):

As in Harpers comment, mixing different types of coating may not end well, especially when they use different solvents. I had a similar experience.

Instead add paint tinter to the epoxy,  take it to a paint store and have them add tint it or add powered pigment to the epoxy.

Large hardware stores will probably refuse to tint it  for you, go to a paint store, speak to a paint expert.